# How to access a file on a remote smb drive using Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, remote-access, smb

So, I'm trying to do some data analysis using Python/Jupyter Notebook. The dataset lives on a remote smb shared drive. How can I read in the data without downloading it to my local machine?

I tried changing the working directory by running:

```
os.chdir('smb://insititution.org/FOLDERPATH')
```

and I get a "No such file or directory" error.

I would appreciate any help anyone can offer!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to map the network drive. This process depends on your OS (e.g. google 'map network device ' on the search engine of your trust).

After your smb is mapped, you should now be able to access via

`os.chdir('//insititution.org/FOLDERPATH')`

for windows OS.

Answer (score -1):

use below argument while starting jupyter notebook

```
--NotebookApp.notebook_dir="\\IP_ADDRESS_FOR_SMB_HOST\share"
```